# Atmega328 Project

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, programming

I want to make a sound system circuit using Atmega328. I want to connect a memory port for store sound files, If I use a single USB, Can I use this single usb for both file transfer to memory and upload program in IC?

Comment: I very much doubt the 328 is fast enough for this   I suggest you take a CPU with a lot more power. (Calculation power I mean. Not voltage*current)

Comment: You cannot host a USB memory stick on an ATmega328.  You can however use an SD card, which you could most easily remove to load sound files with a PC.  Ironically the ATtiny85 will actually do a better job of audio playback (if you don't care about precise speed) because it can clock PWM output more than three times faster.

Comment: @Oldfart you would be mistaken, actual computational load can be quite low as storage devices able to store hours of uncompressed audio are quite inexpensive, the issue is rather with lack of suitable on-chip peripherals.

Answer (score 0):

You want USB, memory card, sound decoding and output (DAC). This is a tall order for a small MCU as atmega328. As you see from the comments, there's not even consensus if it can be done. I recommend you look at some ready-made hardware, such as [SparkFun Qwiic MP3 Trigger](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15165) or [SparkFun MP3 Player Shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12660) for Ardunio.